# 3d ternary surface graphs in R

Tags: r, plot, 3d, contour, ternary

I have a specific question on visualisation of the physical properties of a 3 component mixture in a **3d ternary surface plot**.

So far, I have seen this only in commercial available software.

What I want to have as result is like the figure below.
[3d ternary contour plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Lqb8.png). The example is taken from OriginLab [Originlab Examples](http://www.originlab.com/www/products/GraphGallery.aspx?s=1&&k=Contour%20Boundary,Contour%20Line,Stakced%20Contour,Contour,4D)

Another commercial example is DesignExpert, with similar visualisations.

The basic ternary plot represents the composition of the mixture, whereas the height over the "triangle" represents a physical property (e.g. density) of the mixture.

May question to you is if there is any package available which is able to produce such graphs? In addition to the example, the measured points should be visible and the contour is the fitted model.

Or is there the possibility to generate such graphs in another way within R?

I have already tried the ggtern Package, but it is not suitable, as my mixing models could not be represented as simply ternary contour plot.

As I am using ggplot2 for visualisation my data in my PhD Thesis, I would prefer any solution, which could deliver an analogue style.

Thank you in avdvance

Markus

Comment: Look into `qualityTools::wirePlot3()`.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have seen the qualityTools package before. But as far as I understood the package, you can only rely on predefined mixture experiments e.g. `mdo = mixDesign (3 ,2 , center = FALSE, axial = FALSE, randomize = FALSE, replicates = c(1,1,2,3))`

I have a mixture design which differs significantly in number of design points, which I was not able to bring in the qualityTools format.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this question on the internet only now. Maybe the code below will work for you:

```
trimage <- function( z ){

t1 <- sqrt( length( z ) )

im <- aux <- numeric(0)

   for( i in seq( 1, t1, by = 2 ) ){

   idx <- seq( t1^2, i*t1, by = -t1 ) - ((t1 - i):0)

   #idx <- seq( i*t1, t1^2, by = t1 ) - (i-1) 

   im <- c( im, aux, idx, aux )

   aux <- c( aux, NA )

   }
   z <- matrix( z[im], nr=t1 )
  return( z )
 }


library( fields ) #  use  image.plot  function

tab <- scan()
1.0 0.0 0.0 3.10
0.0 1.0 0.0 0.45
0.0 0.0 1.0 0.35
0.5 0.5 0.0 1.70
0.5 0.0 0.5 4.13
0.0 0.5 0.5 0.27


tab <- matrix( tab, 6,4, byrow=T )

colnames( tab ) <- c("x1", "x2", "x3", "y")

tab <- as.data.frame( tab )

r <- lm( y ~ -1 + x1*x2*x3 - x1:x2:x3, data=tab )

summary( r )

x1 <- seq( 1, 0, len=181 )
x2 <- seq( 1, 0, len=181 )
x123 <- expand.grid( x1=x1, x2=x2 )
x123["x3"] <- 1 - x123["x1"] - x123["x2"]

z <- predict( r, x123 )

ztri <- trimage( z )

image.plot( ztri )

contour( ztri, add=T, lwd=2 )
```